# How to connect to SQL Server using Excel Macro's?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have `SQLEXPRESS` connection details. I want to connect to database using VBA way, and export data from SQL Server table `items` to new sheet in current Excel workbook and specified sheet.

I have tried data import from excel "External Data", that gives me full table when adding it to excel workbook.

How to add to Excel only 1 or 2 columns from my external table?

Updated: my code right now is

```
Sub SQL_Connection()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
    "Data Source="\\localhost\SQLEXPRESS"; " & _
    "Initial Catalog=catalog;" & _
    "User ID=User; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=yes"
con.Open (strCon)
End Sub
```

Getting compile error:

> Syntax error

Comment: What does your existing code look like?

Comment: Have a look at DAO - also, google is your friend. ;) Come back to StackOverflow if you have tried it, and need help with an error. We will be happy to help.

Comment: You need to escape your quotes on this line: `"Data Source=""\\localhost\SQLEXPRESS""; "`. See [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado/12352/retrieving-records-with-a-query) for an example of retrieving records.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create and open the connection with the database. Here I am posting a sample example for three rows:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

With Sheets("Customers")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TESTpc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ExcelSQLServerDemo;Trusted_connection=yes"

   'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "INSERT into dbo.Customers (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName) values ('" & sCustomerId & "', '" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Customers Exported To Database"

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    End With
End Sub
```

Even though there are more efficient ways to export the data. This example is just for your reference purpose.